# iMacros for solving reCAPTCHA

Tags: captcha, recaptcha, imacros

Seeking for a way for solving reCAPTCHA's with iMacros.
Is there any way to solve this captchas, is it possible?

**Here you can find a demo:** google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo

It must not be perfect, it just would be great if is can solve 2 from 30 captchas.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I mean, sure, of course it's possible, but why would you want to do it anyway?

Comment: I can save so much time when it works when creating bit.ly links. I found a way it's works with iMacro, but the quote is bad 3 from ~ 80 works (this captcha service is extremely complex.).

I still optimize it, then I  will post the final code here.

Answer (score 0):

Tyr this code, yet google really suspects it's of a bot:

```
VERSION BUILD=9052613
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
' you need to insert get other url where ReCaptcha is located.
URL GOTO=http://tarex.ru/testdir/recaptcha/recaptcha.php 
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*5 + 1); randomNumber;")
WAIT SECONDS={{!VAR1}}
FRAME F=1 TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=ID:recaptcha-anchor
```

Answer (score 0):

Example with imacros (firefox) for recaptcha (api2 demo) in javascript and jquery:

File: recaptcha_v2.js

```html
//
// The script fill the captcha of recaptcha v2 demo.
//
// Note for users with firefox with the message "Firefox prevented this page from automatically reloading.":
// UNCHECK the option "warn me when pages try to redirect" in your browser
// You find the checkbox under Options > Advanced > General > Accessibility
//
// Please set your browser language to english! (EN)
//

// Loops
var max_loop = 1;

// Url
var myurl = "URL GOTO=https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo\n";
myurl += "";//extra lines

// Submit
mysubmit = "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=*\n";
mysubmit += "";//extra lines

// Debug
var breakOnError = false;
var onBreakAlert = true;
var logFile = true;
var logFileName = 'iimLog.txt';
var max_loop_limit = 500;

//Main
var logFilePath = getiMacrosFolder('Logs')+'\\'+logFileName;

//Performance for recaptchav2
var start_frame_number = 0;
var max_frame_number = 40;

//JQuery
var url_jquery = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js";

// Step 1: Config for 9kw.eu for your apikey
var apikey = "";

//And priority (prio 1-20)
var prio = "1";

(function() {
 // Syntaxcheck: API Key, prio
 if(apikey.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/) && apikey.length <= 50 && apikey.length >= 5){}else{alert_message("API Key \""+apikey+"\" is wrong.");return false;}
 var d = parseFloat(prio); if(d >= 0 && d <= 20){}else{alert_message("Prio \""+prio+"\" is not in the set range.");return false;}

 // only valid number
 if (/[^\d]/.test(max_loop)) {
  alert_message('Please enter a valid number for loop play');
  return false;
 }
 
 max_loop = parseInt(max_loop);
 if(max_loop > max_loop_limit){
  alert_message('Loop limit exceed (' + max_loop_limit + ') , edit the following variable to use your own limit.\n\nvar max_loop_limit = ' + max_loop_limit + ';');
  return false;
 } 
 
 for(var loop = 1; loop <= max_loop; loop++){
  var function_code = "";
  function_code = recaptchav2();
  if(function_code == false && breakOnError == true){
   return false;
  }
 }
})();
//End

// functions
// recaptcha v2
function recaptchav2(){
 //header
 var imacros_header = "SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO\n";
 imacros_header += "SET !ERRORIGNORE NO\n";
 imacros_header += "SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 999\n";
 imacros_header += "SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 999\n";
 
 var imacros_first = "CODE:"+imacros_header+"TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS\n";
 imacros_first += "TAB T=1\n";
 imacros_first += myurl;
 iimPlay(imacros_first)
 
 // JQuery after url goto! (really important)
 loadScriptFromURL(url_jquery);
 $ = window.$,
 JQuery = window.JQuery;
 
 // start execution
 var start = new Date(), end; // for benchmarking
 
 // Step 2: Save the captcha picture to local disk
 // initial click macro
 
 $('iframe[src*="anchor"]').contents().find('.recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark').click();
 
 //Wait a random number of seconds
 wait(Math.floor(Math.random()*3 + 2));
 var checkOK;
 var more_correct_solutions;
 var captchaid;
 var numbers_rc2;

 for(var i3=1;i3<=5;i3++){
  captchaid = "";
  // macro for checking captcha checkbox
  if($('iframe').contents().find('html').find("#recaptcha-anchor").hasClass("recaptcha-checkbox-checked") == true){
   end =+ new Date();
   if(logFile){
    log_message('Captcha is solved\n\rTime spent: '+Math.floor((end-start)/1000));
   }
   //break;
  }else{
   if(i3 > 1){
    //more_correct_solutions = SearchOK("TAG POS=2 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:Multiple<SP>correct<SP>solutions<SP>required<SP>-<SP>please*&&STYLE: CONTENT=EVENT:MOUSEOVER",0+other_frame_number);
    if(more_correct_solutions < 1){
     if($('iframe').contents().find('html').find("#recaptcha-anchor").hasClass("recaptcha-checkbox-checked") != true){
      iimPlay(imacros_first)
      wait(3)
      $('iframe[src*="anchor"]').contents().find('.recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark').click();
      loadScriptFromURL(url_jquery);
      $ = window.$,
      JQuery = window.JQuery;
     }
    }
   }

   numbers_rc2 = $('iframe').contents().find('html').find(".rc-image-tile-wrapper");
   if(numbers_rc2.length > 1){
    for(var i=0; i<numbers_rc2.length; i++){
     var i_high = i + 1;
     if(numbers_rc2.length > 10 && i < 9){
      $('iframe').contents().find('html').find(".rc-image-tile-wrapper").eq(i).append("<span style='position: absolute;width: 18px;left: 0px;top: 0px;border: 1px red black;color:rgb(0, 0, 0);background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);font: bold 18px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;padding: 0px 0px 0px 6px;'>0"+i_high+"</span>");
     }else{
      $('iframe').contents().find('html').find(".rc-image-tile-wrapper").eq(i).append("<span style='position: absolute;width: 18px;left: 0px;top: 0px;border: 1px red black;color:rgb(0, 0, 0);background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);font: bold 18px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;padding: 0px 0px 0px 6px;'>"+i_high+"</span>");
     }
    }
    var recaptcha_v2_error = false;
    
    var text_title;
    $('iframe').contents().find('html').find(".rc-imageselect-desc-no-canonical").html($('iframe').contents().find('html').find(".rc-imageselect-desc-no-canonical").html()+"<br><span style='border: 1px red solid;color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);font: bold 18px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;padding: 0px 0px 0px 8px;'>Type the image numbers <br>&nbsp; without spaces, e.g: 358 </span>");
    $('iframe').contents().find('html').find(".rc-imageselect-desc").html($('iframe').contents().find('html').find(".rc-imageselect-desc").html()+"<br><span style='border: 1px red solid;color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);font: bold 18px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;padding: 0px 0px 0px 8px;'>Type the image numbers <br>&nbsp; without spaces, e.g: 358 </span>");
   }

   var root = window.document.documentElement;
   var canvas = window.document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'html:canvas');
   var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
   
   var selection;
   if(numbers_rc2.length > 1){
    $('div:nth-of-type(2)').css({ transform: 'scale(.70)' });   
    selection = {
     top: $('div:nth-of-type(2)').offset().top,
     left: $('div:nth-of-type(2)').offset().left,
     width: $('div:nth-of-type(2)').width()*0.70,
     height: (($('div:nth-of-type(2)').height() - $('iframe').contents().find('html').find(".rc-footer").height())*0.70),
    };
   }else{
    selection = {
     top: $('div:nth-of-type(2)').offset().top,
     left: $('div:nth-of-type(2)').offset().left,
     width: $('div:nth-of-type(2)').width(),
     height: ($('div:nth-of-type(2)').height() - $('iframe').contents().find('html').find(".rc-footer").height()),
    };
   }
   
   canvas.height = selection.height;
   canvas.width = selection.width;
   
   context.drawWindow(
    window,
    selection.left,
    selection.top,
    selection.width,
    selection.height,
    'rgb(255, 255, 255)'
   );

   //Step 3: Open a new tab, and go to 9kw.eu, and submit the captcha picture
   var imacros_main2 = "CODE:"+imacros_header;
   imacros_main2 += "TAB OPEN\n";
   imacros_main2 += "TAB T=2\n";
   imacros_main2 += "URL GOTO=http://www.9kw.eu/grafik/form_base64.html\n";
   //The apikey is used to identify each of our customers, which you can get from the our page. It is assigned to the CONTENT.
   imacros_main2 += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=NAME:apikey CONTENT="+apikey+"\n";
   //Priority in our system like min. 0 to max. 20 (cost +0-20)
   imacros_main2 += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=NAME:prio CONTENT="+prio+"\n";
   //Options for the form. See more under http://www.9kw.eu/grafik/form.html and http://www.9kw.eu/api.html
   imacros_main2 += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ACTION:/index.cgi ATTR=NAME:selfsolve CONTENT=NO\n";
   imacros_main2 += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ACTION:/index.cgi ATTR=NAME:confirm CONTENT=NO\n";
   imacros_main2 += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ACTION:/index.cgi ATTR=NAME:case-sensitive CONTENT=NO\n";
   imacros_main2 += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ACTION:/index.cgi ATTR=NAME:nomd5 CONTENT=YES\n";
   //We need only numbers for this captcha
   if(numbers_rc2.length > 1){
    imacros_main2 += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ACTION:/index.cgi ATTR=NAME:numeric CONTENT=YES\n";
   }
   imacros_main2 += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=NAME:source CONTENT=imacros\n";
   // recaptcha v2 for non text captcha or recaptcha for text captcha
   if(numbers_rc2.length > 1){
    imacros_main2 += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=NAME:oldsource CONTENT=recaptchav2\n";
   }else{
    imacros_main2 += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=NAME:oldsource CONTENT=recaptcha\n";
   }
   //The path of the captcha picture saved is assigned to the CONTENT
   imacros_main2 += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=NAME:file-upload-01 CONTENT="+canvas.toDataURL('image/png', '').split(',')[1]+"\n";
   //Submit the formdata to 9kw.eu
   imacros_main2 += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=TYPE:submit\n";
   //Clean the !EXTRACT variable for the next task
   imacros_main2 += "SET !EXTRACT NULL\n";
   //Extract the characters that are recoginzed from the picture of captcha.
   imacros_main2 += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=NAME:result EXTRACT=TXT\n";
   iimPlay(imacros_main2)
   var answer = iimGetLastExtract();
   //Step 4: Check the captcha answer (text or nothing like #EANF# = Extraction Anchor Not Found)
   if(answer == "#EANF#" || answer == "ERROR NO USER"){
    answer = "";
   }
   
   //Extract the captchaid from your captcha submit
   var imacros_main3 = "CODE:";
   imacros_main3 += "SET !EXTRACT NULL\n";
   imacros_main3 += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=NAME:captchaid EXTRACT=TXT\n";
   imacros_main3 += "SET captchaid {{!EXTRACT}}\n";
   imacros_main3 += "TAB CLOSE\n";
   iimPlay(imacros_main3)
   captchaid = iimGetLastExtract();
   
   //Clean the !EXTRACT variable for the next task
   var imacros_main4 = "SET !EXTRACT NULL\n";
   iimPlay(imacros_main4)
   
   //Display extracted data (only for debug)
   //iimDisplay("captchaid: "+captchaid+"\nanswer: "+answer)
   
   //Step 5: Fill the recognized characters to the verification box (Click the pictures 1..16)
   if(numbers_rc2.length > 1){
    $('div:nth-of-type(2)').css({ transform: 'scale(1.0)' });
    
    var myarray = answer.split('');
    if(myarray.length < 2){
     alert_message("No answer found. Check the history on 9kw.eu!");
     if(breakOnError){
      return false;
     }else{
      break;
     }
    }else{
     for(var i = 0;i < myarray.length; i++){
      if(myarray[i].match(/^[0-9]+$/)){
       if(numbers_rc2.length > 10){
        var two_values;
        if(myarray[i+1].match(/^[0-9]+$/)){
         two_values = myarray[i]+myarray[i+1];
        }else{
         two_values = myarray[i];
        }
        i += 1;
        two_values = two_values.replace("0", "");
        two_values = parseFloat(two_values) - 1;
        if(two_values == ""){
         two_values = 0;
        }
        $('iframe').contents().find('html').find(".rc-image-tile-wrapper").eq(two_values).click();
       }else{
        myarray[i] = parseFloat(myarray[i]) - 1;
        if(myarray[i] == ""){
         myarray[i] = 0;
        }
        $('iframe').contents().find('html').find(".rc-image-tile-wrapper").eq(myarray[i]).click();
       }
      }
     }
    }
   }else{//text captcha
    SearchFrame("TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:default-response CONTENT="+answer,start_frame_number);
   }
    
   //Click the Verify button
   if(numbers_rc2.length > 1){
    SearchFrame("EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR=\"HTML>BODY>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV\" BUTTON=0",start_frame_number);
   }else{
    SearchFrame("TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:recaptcha-verify-button",start_frame_number);
   }
  }
  wait(1)
   
  // Submit
  var solved_OK;
  if($('iframe').contents().find('html').find("#recaptcha-anchor").hasClass("recaptcha-checkbox-checked") == true){
   if($('iframe').contents().find('html').find("#recaptcha-anchor").hasClass("recaptcha-checkbox-checked") == true){
    solved_OK = 1;
   }
   SearchFrame(mysubmit,start_frame_number);
   loadScriptFromURL(url_jquery);
   $ = window.$,
   JQuery = window.JQuery;
  }else{
   solved_OK = 0;
   if($('iframe').contents().find('html').find('.rc-imageselect-incorrect-response').css('display') == 'block'){
    more_correct_solutions = 1;
   }else{
    more_correct_solutions = "";
   }
  }
   
  //Step 6: Check and send the captcha feedback back to the captcha service (OK:1, NotOK:2, EN: Right/False, DE: Richtig/Falsch)
  var htmlcode = "";
  if(captchaid.length > 0){
   if($('iframe').contents().find('html').find("#recaptcha-anchor").hasClass("recaptcha-checkbox-checked") == true){
    var imacros_main4b = "CODE:TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:recaptcha-success EXTRACT=TXT\n";
    iimPlay(imacros_main4b)
    htmlcode = iimGetLastExtract();
   }
  }
      
  var feedback;
  if(htmlcode.match(/Juhu/) || htmlcode.match(/Hooray/) || more_correct_solutions < 1 || solved_OK == 1){
   feedback = 1;
  }else{
   feedback = 2;
  }
   
  if(captchaid.length > 0){
   var imacros_main5 = "CODE:TAB OPEN\n";
   imacros_main5 += "TAB T=2\n";
   imacros_main5 += "URL GOTO=http://www.9kw.eu/index.cgi?source=imacros&action=usercaptchacorrectback&apikey="+apikey+"&correct="+feedback+"&id="+captchaid+"\n";
   imacros_main5 += "TAB CLOSE\n";
   iimPlay(imacros_main5)
  }

  if(feedback == "1"){
   break;
  }
 }
 return;
}

// random between 1 and 9
function rand(){
 return Math.floor(Math.random()*9) + 1;
}

// wait function like wait(2) for two seconds
function wait(waittime){
 iimPlay("CODE: WAIT SECONDS="+waittime+"\n");
 return;
}

// wait function like wait(2) for two seconds
function getextract(shortcode){
 iimPlay("CODE: "+shortcode);
 return iimGetLastExtract();
}

// date functione
function tempfile_date() {
 now = new Date();
 year = "" + now.getFullYear();
 month = "" + (now.getMonth() + 1); if (month.length == 1) { month = "0" + month; }
 day = "" + now.getDate(); if (day.length == 1) { day = "0" + day; }
 hour = "" + now.getHours(); if (hour.length == 1) { hour = "0" + hour; }
 minute = "" + now.getMinutes(); if (minute.length == 1) { minute = "0" + minute; }
 second = "" + now.getSeconds(); if (second.length == 1) { second = "0" + second; }
 return year + month + day + "_" + hour + minute + second;
}

// find frame with true or false as return
function SearchOK(checkcode,firstframenumber,lastframenumber){
 var check = "CODE:";
 check += "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n";
 check += "SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0" + "\n"; 
 check += "FRAME F={{i}}" + "\n"; 
 check += "SET !ERRORIGNORE NO" + "\n";
   
 if (checkcode != ""){
  check += checkcode + "\n"; 
 }else{
  return 0;
 }
  
 if(/^\d+$/.test(firstframenumber)) {
  frame = firstframenumber;
 }else{
  frame = 1;
 }
 
 if(/^\d+$/.test(lastframenumber)) {
  frame2 = lastframenumber;
 }else{
  frame2 = total_frame_number;
 }

 for(var i=frame;i<=frame2;i++){
  iimSet("i",i)

  if(iimPlay(check) == true){
   return 1;
  }
 }
 return 0;
}

// find frame with the framenumber as return
function SearchFrame(checkcode,firstframenumber){
 var check = "CODE:";
 check += "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n";
 check += "SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0" + "\n"; 
 check += "FRAME F={{i}}" + "\n"; 
 check += "SET !ERRORIGNORE NO" + "\n";
   
 if (checkcode != ""){
  check += checkcode + "\n"; 
 }else{
  return 0;
 }
  
 if(/^\d+$/.test(firstframenumber)) {
  frame = firstframenumber;
 }else{
  frame = 1;
 }

 for(var i=frame;i<=max_frame_number;i++){
  iimSet("i",i)

  //if the result of the macro is true save frame number and break
  if(iimPlay(check) == true){
   frame = i;
   break;
  }
 }
 //return frame number
 return frame;
}

// Get the imacros folder
function getiMacrosFolder(folderName){
   var pname;
   switch (folderName){
      case "Macros" :
         pname = "defsavepath";
         break;
      case "DataSources" :
         pname = "defdatapath";
         break;
      case "Downloads" :
         pname = "defdownpath";
         break;
      case "Logs" :
         pname = "deflogpath";
         break;
      default :
         throw folderName + " is not a valid iMacros folder name";
         break;
   }
   return imns.Pref.getFilePref(pname).path;
}

// Logfunction
function log_message(msg) {
 var time = new Date().toString().replace(/\s+GMT.*/, '');
 msg = time + ' - ' + msg + '\n';
 var file_o = imns.FIO.openNode(logFilePath);
 imns.FIO.appendTextFile(file_o, msg);
}

// Logfunction
function alert_message(msg){
 if(logFile){
  log_message(msg);
 }

 iimDisplay(msg);

 if(onBreakAlert){
  alert(msg);
 }
}

// jquery
function loadScriptFromURL(url) {
 var request = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1'].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIXMLHttpRequest),
 async = false;
 request.open('GET', url, async);
 request.send();
 if(request.status !== 200){
  var message = 'an error occurred while loading script at url: ' + url + ', status: ' + request.status;
  iimDisplay(message);
  return false;
 }
 eval(request.response);
 return true;
}
```